# How to use COM components completely in core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, com

I'm using dynamic to access COM components in core 3.1, and it's not work.

Try with [A small wrapper around COM interop](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12587#issuecomment-534611966), it's almost ok except index property such as `var sheet = wb.Sheets[1];` I had to override TryGetIndex function. So I must get the type of a comobject with
[Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523417/Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects), but it's not work in core 3.1:

```
System.MissingMethodException:“Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeForITypeInfo(IntPtr)'.”
```

And

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\CustomMarshalers\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CustomMarshalers.dll

C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_custommarshalers_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.1_none_e788457a14459849\CustomMarshalers.dll

has been tried.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't use dynamic to mean that I have to refer to many libraries.And maybe there's a version problem.I'm so sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved based on CyrusNajmabadi's[reply](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12587#issuecomment-598445917)

```
public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
{
    result = WrapIfRequired(
        _instance.GetType()
            .InvokeMember(
                "Item",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                Type.DefaultBinder,
                _instance,
                indexes
            ));
    return true;
}
```

It's worked!Thanks!